# What does the CMSA/CD method being deterministic and distributed mean?

Tags: networking

I found, on Wikipedia, that both the Token Ring and CSMA/CD methods are deterministic & distributed but I don't understand what deterministic and distributed means in this context.

Can somebody explain these words generally and then applied to these 2 methods?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about networking. I do not believe the question is suitable for migration as the question needs more explanation. If you improve your question another site in the network might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

CSMA/CD is **not** deterministic, while Token Ring **is** deterministic.

This means that with TokenRing you are sure you will be able to send your packet at some point (that might be in a long time but it will happen for sure).

While with CSMA/CD if you are very very not lucky, every time you try to send your packet someone else try on the same time, therefore you can't be sure that you will be able to send your packet. Of course the more you try, the higher the probability of being able to send the packet gets ... though it is never sure (you would need an infinite time for that).